# How to exclude GRPC generated C# code from code coverage

Tags: code-coverage, grpc-c#, coverlet

We have a C# GRPC service. It references the "Grpc.AspNetCore" NuGet package, which in turn pulls in the "Grpc.Tools" package. From what I can [gather](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md), those tools convert our "proto" files in the project into auto-generated code.

The Tests project references the service project, and has NuGet packages Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk, NUnit3TestAdapter, NUnit, coverlet.collector, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis and some others which I don't think are relevant. We're using `dotnet test` to run the tests, with the "XPlat Code Coverage" collector.

Someone previously raised a [question to Coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/1141) about excluding the generated code from the code coverage, and they were just waiting for the Grpc.Tools to be changed to attribute things as having the `GeneratedCode` attribute. It looks like that has been done, because I can see that the generated code *usually* has that attribute.

So I added the following section to our ".runsettings" file, to exclude things with that attribute:

```
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <ExcludeByAttribute>GeneratedCodeAttribute</ExcludeByAttribute>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
```

And this has improved things. But not entirely, partly because that attribute isn't always in place. For example, it doesn't put it on this field:

```
    private static readonly pb::MessageParser<GetRedactedRequest> _parser = new pb::MessageParser<GetRedactedRequest>(()
```

or this one

```
    static readonly string __ServiceName = "MyService.v1.Redacted";
```

There are also places where the attribute *is* there, but coverlet still reports these as "uncovered" (the following is taken from the generated report, so some of these lines are truncated):

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("grpc_csharp_plugin", null)]
static readonly grpc::Marshaller<global::MyService.V1.GetRedactedRequest> __Marshaller_MyService_v1_GetR
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("grpc_csharp_plugin", null)]
static readonly grpc::Marshaller<global::MyService.V1.GetRedactedResponse> __Marshaller_MyService_v1_Get

[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("grpc_csharp_plugin", null)]
static readonly grpc::Method<global::MyService.V1.GetRedactedRequest, global::MyService.V1.GetRedactedRe
    grpc::MethodType.Unary,
    __ServiceName,
    "GetRedacted",
    __Marshaller_MyService_v1_GetRedactedRequest,
    __Marshaller_MyService_v1_GetRedactedResponse);
```

There is another way we could exclude it, by putting the generated classes in a particular namespace, and then excluding everything from that namespace; but that would require us each time we add a new "proto" to ensure it's in a namespace that is excluded. I'm looking for a way where I can just exclude all of the generated GRPC code.

I'm not sure whether it's a bug on the Grpc Tools, or on Coverlet (or both); or perhaps we shouldn't be excluding that from coverage - perhaps we should be unit testing it (although that doesn't feel like a "unit" test). How can we exclude this generated GRPC code from our code coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to exclude the files generated by Grpc.Tools is to exclude the generated files using coverlet `<ExcludeByFile>` and having a pattern that matches the cs files in the output directory specified in the Grpc.Tools (defaults to under the `obj` directory).

Comment: Thanks. We keep all of our Proto files in a "Protos" folder, so the solution was `<ExcludeByFile>**/obj/**/Protos/*.cs</ExcludeByFile>` alongside the `ExcludeByAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like you can move all proto files to standalone project with no other code or just helpers that can also be excluded from Code Coverage, then you can add attribute `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute]` at assembly level in the project

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: As described in the question, the assembly contains the implementation of the service described in the proto file, so I'm struggling to see how "If you have all proto files in standalone project with no other code" would ever be a suitable answer to this question.

Comment: I rephrase it, I hope it's better for your. I just wanted to shared my approach that is working fine in my project

Comment: I understand exactly what those attributes do, and I do them myself as you have shown, in other places. But I still don't understand... how you could have a proto file defining a service being the only thing in the project? I just don't think this is an appropriate answer to this question.

Comment: Simple I have more then one implementation of the gRPC service, so to not copy proto files(also all code generation happen in that shared project) and keep them in one place each all implementation referencing that project. As the question is `How can we exclude this generated GRPC code from our code coverage?` and all generated code would be included in Code Coverage